# Testing in android google play

Tags: android

First i tried downloading my beta testing app in my samsung tab and it refused i didnt know what the problem is, I went and updated my app now 
I wanted to upload a new version of the edited APK app for testing  again and it wont upload, it keeps telling me version code is 1. I have configured the Manifest and done the necessary.

In my manifest i added

```
 android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.2">
```

Now any advice as to what would be causing this will be appreciated.

Comment: As per Google play error which you posted means that  version is not update in New build. Can you please try to set version code  = 3 and clean and build again.

Comment: i tried that but it wont take it.

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia I have done all that but nothing up to now. It is sad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version code

as per Google

Alpha/Beta availability
Alpha and beta APKs need to have a higher version code than production APKs to be available for testing.

To be available for alpha testers, alpha APKs need to have a higher version code than beta APKs.
If a beta APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha APK, the alpha version will automatically be deactivated.
If a Production APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha or beta APK, the alpha and/or beta version will automatically be deactivated.
Alpha testing group users are eligible for the alpha, beta, or production version of your app with the highest version code that is compatible with their device. Beta testing group users are only eligible for the beta or production version of your app with the highest version code that is compatible with their device.

> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: I did read the link i have actually tried all that, changed the version code but it keeps saying i am updating 1